# Tree as instance of functor and foldable

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, functor

I am writing a little code for a hw problem which asks us to make a definition of tree an instance of functor and foldable. When I write the code below:

```
 import Data.Foldable
 import Data.Monoid

 data Tree a = Leaf a
              | Node [Tree a] 
     deriving (Show) 

 instance Functor (Tree) where
    fmap f (Leaf a) = Leaf (f a) 
    fmap f (Node [Tree a]) = fmap f [Tree a]

 instance Foldable (Tree) where
    foldMap f (Leaf a) = f a
    foldMap f (Node [Tree a]) = foldMap f `mappend` [Tree a]
```

the following error appears:

```
hw.hs:10:19:
Not in scope: data constructor `Tree'
Perhaps you meant `True' (imported from Prelude)

hw.hs:10:38:
Not in scope: data constructor `Tree'
Perhaps you meant `True' (imported from Prelude)

hw.hs:14:22:
Not in scope: data constructor `Tree'
Perhaps you meant `True' (imported from Prelude)

hw.hs:14:54:
Not in scope: data constructor `Tree'
Perhaps you meant `True' (imported from Prelude)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

[[Update]]

I have made changes to the code as per the suggestion made in the answer below. Here is a link to the code with the error. It would be great if anyone would take a look at it and tell me where I am wrong.

http://snipt.org/Bahjg5

Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

You can't write this:

```
fmap f (Node [Tree a]) = ...
```

because `Tree` is a data type not a data constructor. In a pattern-match you can only use data constructors, which would be `Leaf` or `Node` in this case. Here, you don't even need to match each constructor for the child trees, because you are passing the entire list straight through anyway:

```
fmap f (Node t) = fmap f t
```

But actually there is also another error there. The result of `fmap` still needs to be a `Tree` so you need to put the result back inside a `Node`:

```
fmap f (Node t) = Node (fmap f t)
```

just like you are already doing with the `Leaf` case.

---

You can think of `fmap` as something that modifies values *inside* the structure, but without changing the *shape* of the structure at all. ie. mapping over a list will produce a list of the same length, and mapping over a tree should produce an identical tree, with all the same branches, but with different values in the leaf nodes.

You can think of a `fold` as something that completely removes the structure, and then finds a way to combine all the values from leaf nodes into a single value. The Type of `foldMap` helps:

```
 foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => 
         (a -> m) -- mapping function from `a` to the monoid result
      -> t a      -- A tree node containing values of type `a`
      -> m        -- a monoid
```

The result of `foldMap` should not be a `Tree`! It's just the values, transformed with the mapping function and combined using their `Monoid` instance.

Comment: Technically `Tree` is a type of constructor: A type constructor. So it makes types vs `Node` which makes values

Comment: @jozefg Slightly picky! But ok, I changed it :)

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks a lot! I have made changes to your code as per your suggestion but it still throws error message

You can view the updated code with the error msg here:

 http://snipt.org/Bahjg5

Comment: @user2994154 When you're defining `fmap` for a `(Tree a)`, the first argument for `fmap` is a function that takes `(a -> b)`. In your definition `Node (fmap f t)` you're expecting `fmap` to be a `Tree a -> Treee b`. Why not `Node (fmap (fmap f) t)` that is equivalent of `Node [fmap f a | a <- t]`.

Comment: @homam I just figured that out but thanks for your feedback. Will the foldable instance work out in similar fashion?

Comment: @user2994154  If you think fold as `fold :: Tree a -> a`, then the result of folding a `Tree a` is an `a`. Notice `fold` takes a `Tree a` and folds it into one `a`. Here `a` itself has to be `Foldable` or more generally `Monoid`. Similarly in `foldMap :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> b` `b` must be `Monoid`. Hence `foldMap f (Leaf t) = (f t)` not `.. = Leaf (f t)`.